# where is "killer gegls from outer space" source code

Tags: application-development, games, source-code

I want to modify the game Killer gegls from outer space. Linux OS Easter egg. 
only I cant find the source-code. Where is it?

Comment: It is within gnome , but I can not find the location documented. You might ask on the gnome mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/desktop/2.32/2.32.0/sources/gnome-panel-2.32.0.2.tar.bz2
$ tar xf gnome-panel-2.32.0.2.tar.bz2
$ grep -r easter gnome-panel-2.32.0.2
gnome-panel-2.32.0.2/gnome-panel/nothing.cP:/*thy evil easter egg*/
```